# Copying Entire Worksheet from one Excel to another

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I would like to copy the entire worksheet from one Closed Excel file to the currently open excel file however I do not want to use a range as the amount of rows in the file will vary.

The code I am using to rereive data from within a range is

```
Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
  SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, Header As Boolean,         
UseHeaderRow As Boolean)
' 30-Dec-2007, working in Excel 2000-2007
Dim rsCon As Object
Dim rsData As Object
Dim szConnect As String
Dim szSQL As String
Dim lCount As Long

' Create the connection string.
If Header = False Then
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
    End If
Else
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    End If
End If

If SourceSheet = "" Then
    ' workbook level name
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
Else
    ' worksheet level name or range
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
End If

On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rsCon.Open szConnect
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
If Not rsData.EOF Then

    If Header = False Then
        TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
    Else
        'Add the header cell in each column if the last argument is True
        If UseHeaderRow Then
            For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
                TargetRange.Cells(1, 1 + lCount).Value = _
                rsData.Fields(lCount).Name
            Next lCount
            TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Else
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        End If
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
End If

' Clean up our Recordset object.
rsData.Close
Set rsData = Nothing
rsCon.Close
Set rsCon = Nothing
Exit Sub

SomethingWrong:
MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & SourceFile, _
       vbExclamation, "Error"
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Any help with importing the entire worksheet and all of its rows/column would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
Dim wbkSource As Workbook
Set wbkSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\BookFromWhichToCopy.xlsx")
wbkSource.Sheets("MySheet").Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
wbkSource.Close
```

Note that you can call sheets by their name `.Sheets("MySheet")` or by their number in the workbook `.Sheets(2)`, whichever suits you best.

Comment: This does not work, says the worksheet is too large and I should copy and paste it. I have managed to get this working now however whenever I load the file it opens the file I am copying from which is annoying. Its probably happening as the file is not stored locally.

Comment: I'm not quite following... Does it work or not? What did you add to make it work? Yes, this opens the workbook. But *anything* you do to read the file will open the workbook file in one way or another.